# @Async giving me error in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

This is main application class:

```
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        return executor;
    }

}
```

This is service class:

```
@Component
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductHandler productHandler;

    @Async
    @Override
    public List<String> getAllCategories() {
        final List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        return finalList;
    }

}
```

This is the controller class:

```
@RestController
public class ProductResource {

    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl;

    @GetMapping("/categories")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getAllCategories() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.productServiceImpl.getAllCategories(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have annotated the service implementation method with `@Async` but I get this error:

> Action:
>
> Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.

If I try annotating the controller I get empty response to my get request. I have try every thing including setting `proxyTargetClass` to true.

Comment: Either ditch your `ProductService` interface or start using it by using `ProductService` instead of `ProductserviceImpl` in your controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please tell me why I can't apply async to ProductserviceImpl?

Comment: I nowhere said that. I said you should be either be programming to interface (use the interface instead of the implementation in your controller) or ditch the interface all together.

Comment: Rebuild the project.

Comment: I autowired ProductService. I got empty response, but when I removed @Async annotation I got the response. Could you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) annotation, you have to get familiar with the rules that have to be respected while using it:

- The method must be `public` only
- It cannot be called from a method within the same class (self-invocation)
- If a return type is used, it has to be wrapped in [`Future<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), ex. [`CompletableFuture<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

So you get:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> categories = this.productServiceImpl.getAllCategories();
```

The further handling is driven by the implementation of `Future` where you can either block the execution or `join` more of them into a single response...